# CodeIgniter form_validation is not showing errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

I'm really new in CodeIgniter and I have problem with `form_validation`:

- I created a controller to authenticate and this is my controller

==========================================================================

```
public function auth()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('from','url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'username',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->load->view('login');
    } else {
        echo ';) like a boss';
    }
    }
}
```

================================================================

- and also I created view with login.
  Here is view code

================================================================

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="login">
        <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
        <?php
        $this->load->helper('form');
        echo validation_errors();
        echo form_open('login/auth');
        $username = form_input(array('name' => 'username', 'placeholder' => 'Username or Email'));
        $password = form_password(array('name' => 'password', 'placeholder' => 'Password'));
        $checkbox = form_checkbox('remember', '1');
        $submit = form_submit('submit', 'Login');
        ?>
        <p><?= $username ?></p>
        <p><?= $password ?></p>
        <p class="remember_me">
            <label>
                <?= $checkbox ?>
                Remember me on this computer
            </label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit"><?= $submit ?></p>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: please check your controller there is a typo `$this->load->helper(array('from','url'));` what `from` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one angle bracket is more in your code

```
public function auth()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('from','url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'username',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->load->view('login');
    } else {
        echo ';) like a boss';
    }`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove one closing bracket from bottom
2. change to `$this->load->helper(array('form','url'));`

   ```
   public function auth() {

     $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));

     $this->load->library('form_validation');

     $rules = array(
       array(
           'field' => 'username',
           'label' => 'username',
           'rules' => 'required'
       ),
       array(
           'field' => 'password',
           'label' => 'Password',
           'rules' => 'required'
       )
      );
      $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->load->view('form-new');
      } else {
         echo ';) like a boss';
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

This would be the codeignitor helper which is reduces human effors

```
 $this->load->helper(array('from','url'));

This would be the library function which validation process works

$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');


 if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
//code       
  }else{
// code
}
```

// for set rules in codeignitor please check the following url

Reference :

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html